# Json file not loading

Tags: jquery, json

I have a folder structure like this.

- [ site ]

  - [ js ]
  - [ json ]

    - hints.json
  - page.html

Now when I launch my page.html I have a button that when I click is going to load my hints.json file.
Here is my script for loading the json.

```
$(function(){

  var jsonURL = "json/hints.json";
  var butt = $('.button .hints li');
  butt.find('a').click(function(evt){

    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(value){
        console.log(" title = ", value.intro[0].title);
    });



  }); 

});
```

Json file structure.

```
{
    "intro": [
                {"title": "title text", "copy": "copy text1"}, 
                {"title": "title text", "copy": "copy text1"}
             ],
    "active":[
                {"title": "Title text for page active", "copy": "copy text"}
             ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this would not work.

Update: This is been tested locally not from a server.

Here is a jsfiddle example even though I'm trying to get it to work locally.
http://jsfiddle.net/r3bPC/1/

Comment: Did you miss type that JSON or is that really what is getting sent to you? If so, it's wrong.

Comment: use Firefox + Firebug, open the NET tab and see your AJAX request. You will see the response or a 404 error.

Comment: Its what I typed. What is wrong with the json structure. Even if its wrong I guess first things first would that stop the load of it. I'm getting no errors. The load method doesn't get fired when I do a console log from it

Comment: Nothing under Firebug net tab as its been tested locally. Not from a server and not using ajax.

Comment: you said `quest.json` but actually you are loading `hints.json` ... just in case ...

Comment: Upps sorry mistyped it should be hints.json. But it still doesn't load. Is there a security issue when loading locally maybe

Comment: Are you running a local web server or getting through a file url?

Comment: no local server just file url

Comment: Do you have `active.title` between `"` in your real code?

Comment: @Chapsterj see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json file structure.

```
{
    "intro": [
                {"title": "title text", "copy": "copy text1"}, 
                {"title": "title text", "copy": "copy text1"}
             ],
    "active":[
                {"title": Title text for page active, "copy": "copy text"}
             ]
}
```

Dump into http://jsonlint.com/ ....

```
Parse error on line 14:
...           "title": Titletextforpageacti
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Well there's your problem.

**Part 2**

Grab that JS:

```
$(function(){

  var jsonURL = "json/hints.json";
  butt.find('a').click(function(evt){

    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json){
        // $("#title").text(json.name);
        console.log(" title = ", json.intro[0].title);
    });

});
```

Run it through http://jshint.com/ ...

```
Errors:

Line 4 butt.find('a').click(function(evt){
'butt' is not defined.
Line 1$(function(){
Unmatched '{'.
Line 11});
Expected ')' and instead saw ''.
Line 11});
Missing semicolon.
```

Well there's your other problem.

ps, undefined butts scare me.

Comment: Thanks Incognito I fixed the json string. as for the butt being undefined. Its not its just not showing the butt variable. When I do a consoloe.log it shows the button event working. Its the $.getJSON thats not loading. I updated my code to show what butt is.  var butt = $('.button a');

Comment: Also after I ran my code in jshint it passed correctly. So I know its the  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json){
thats not getting executed for some reason.

Comment: Pay attention to what jshint is telling you. You haven't closed off something. Match up all your brackets. JS Hint tells you what it was.

Comment: Incognito I updated my click code so it passes the validation but again its the $.getJSON thats not getting executed.

Comment: Ok it worked not sure what that was because it validated correctly then I tested it and it didn't work. Then I tested it again with emptying my cache and it worked. Thanks to you all for your help.

Comment: One other question would this be a good way to structure my json. I wanted to use the intro and active as a page ID. So my page have ids with these names. If anyone thinks there is a better way please let me know

Answer (score 0):

complete tried and tested code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'hints.json',
dataType:'json',
success:function(json){
alert(json.intro[0].title); //this alerts title text
},
error:function(){
alert("dssdsdd");
}
});


});

</script>
```

or

```
$.getJSON("hints.json", function(json){

        alert(json.intro[0].title);
    });
```

hints.json

```
{
    "intro": [
                {"title": "title text", "copy": "copy text1"}, 
                {"title": "title text", "copy": "copy text1"}
             ],
    "active":[
                {"title": "Title text for page active", "copy": "copy text"}
             ]
}
```

[**getJSON success callback**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("hints.json", function() {
  alert("success");
  alert(json.intro[0].title);
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: Why would it not work using $.getJSON(). Why would I want to use a a $.ajax( ) call when I'm not calling ajax?

Comment: Ok thats great but its not working for me :) I'm sorry but my frustration level is kind of high right now at this code. So sorry if I seem short. So you even tried it like I have with a path like this: json/hints.json using a button click like I have setup in my jsfiddle example and my local example

Comment: try like `butt.click(function(evt){...
`

Comment: 3nigma can you use a success callback with $.getJSON